# Is there a reason, that Qt has not complete header files?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, header-files

I am currently working with Qt Creator on a project involving the Property Stores from the Windows APIs.

In the only docs Microsofts states to include the `functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h` file to get access to the Proterty Keys. Unfortunately, [the header file that was delivered with Qt Creator](https://github.com/EddieRingle/portaudio/blob/master/src/hostapi/wasapi/mingw-include/FunctionDiscoveryKeys_devpkey.h) only contained one single Property Key `PKEY_Device_FriendlyName`, while the same file from the windows SDK contained way more and looked like [this](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/include/functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h).

I always thought that QtCreator simply copied all Windows SDK header files.

When do Qt Creator header files not match the ones with the Windows SDK?
Will I run into any nasty problems, when I just copy the full header file into my project?

Comment: `Qt` is a wrapper framework for OS as I know. It just wraps the functionality provided by the OS with general functionality. Having said that I meant that it provides an abstraction over the OS. There could be some functionalities not covered (maybe yet) by `Qt`. This is my subjective opinion.

Comment: Also please take under the consideration the fact, that `Qt` and `Qt Creator` are not the same things. The `Qt` is a company, which provides framework/library with the same name. The `Qt Creator` is an IDE, which is used to easily develop `Qt` applications

Comment: When Qt is just a wrapper for the OS, then there shouldn't be any differences between the header files, right?

Comment: what header files you mean? `Qt windows` and `Qt linux` or `Qt` and `windows`?

Comment: I meant Qt and windows

Comment: I think yes. `Qt` doesn't promise to wrap/provide all the features the OS provides.

Comment: Very unfortunate, but thank you!

Comment: I believe you can reach the target investigating the `Qt` provided features deeper. Probably there is a header file or a class that can provide you the requested information. If you tell detailed what you searching for probably I could give you a more specific direction. But for now, I'd suggest you have a look at [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) class.